# Ray[tune]: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: hyperparameters, ray

I am trying to tune a list of parameters using `Ray[Tune]`. When I run it, I get the following error:
`FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified`

I am using the `bayesopt` as the search_algorithm. It was running fine earlier.

Details Error: please see the attached screenshot

[image: detailed_error]

Comment: I have checked in Ubuntu 20.04. It is working fine. It seems to be a problem with Windows.

Comment: I have the same problem, since the last Win11 update. Was running completely fine for weeks before in the same env.